# Powershell not executing in order written

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the Powershell below. The problem is that that Get-ADUser commands are both appearing below the Keypress instead of in order from top down.

Powershell is currently executing this script below in order of: Write-Host, $var Read-Host, Unlock, Keypress, Get-ADUser, Get-ADUser, exit window.

I would like it to execute: Write-Host, $var Read-Host, Get-ADUser, Keypress, Unlock, Sleep 2 seconds, Get-ADUser, Keypress, exit window.

This would show the before and after of the AD account status after the keypress.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "This is set to unlock account in *REDACTED*"
$ADAcc = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter UserID of Account"
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $ADAcc -or samaccountname -like $ADAcc} | select SamAccountName, Enabled
Write-Host "Press any key to continue unlocking account"
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
Unlock-ADAccount -Server *REDACTED* -Identity $ADAcc
Start-Sleep -s 2
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $ADAcc -or samaccountname -like $ADAcc} | select SamAccountName, Enabled
Write-Host "Press any key to exit..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Comment: pipe the statements to `Format-Table` or `Out-Host` to force synchronized output

Comment: It would be?: ```Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $ADAcc -or samaccountname -like $ADAcc} | select SamAccountName, Enabled | Format-Table ```

Comment: correct, but in all appearances of that

Comment: so you can do `Write-Host "This is set ....." | Out-Host` and `Get-ADUser ..... | Out-Host` and so on, this way you force synchronized output to the console